# Android Nougat receive via socket error

Tags: android, android-service, serversocket

I have made an application that send and receive data via socket it works in Android os < 7.0.0 but when i launche this application in android nougat(7.0.0) it display an error when receiving replay it display android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error at lign (dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply);) so how can i fix this error thanks for yours attention.

**Code:**

String msgReply = "&sim1$extr€"+getIpAddressonly()+"?8080.wifi/";

try 
{

dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply); // error at this line

}

catch (IOException e) {
                                                            e.printStackTrace();

}

Comment: You will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException on Android 4, 5 and 6 too.

Comment: @greenapps no i have compiled the app in android 4.1 and 5 and 6 and it work fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your network I/O off the main (UI) thread. Start a background thread to do network I/O.